# Difference between "step" and "step in" in the MATLAB debugger

Tags: matlab, debugging

What is the difference between "Step" and "Step in" in the MATLAB debugger? As far as I have tested them in some debugging so far they gave me the same steps and results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `dbstep` (or the debugger tool "Step") executes the next line of code. It does not stop within that function, even if that function is implemented in MATLAB code and contains breakpoints.

The command `dbstep in` (or the debugger tool "Step In") also executes the next line of code, but if that line is a call to a function implemented in MATLAB code (i.e. not a built-in), it will enter that function and stop at the next line of code within the function.

If the next line is not a call to a function implemented in MATLAB code, `dbstep` and `dbstep in` are equivalent.

Answer (score 5):

When you use `step in` on a function call, you will enter said function. `step` is used to move to the next line. When you use them on lines without function calls, they are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

See the Matlab doc: [dbstep](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/ref/dbstep.html)

Basically, Step executes the next line, even if there is a call to complex function/other script. Step In jumps in the code on the called function if possible, else executes the entire line.